# PHP: How to capitalize the nth letter of a string?

Tags: php, string

Everyone knows how to capitalize the first letter of a string (`ucfirst`) but what about the 2nd or Nth letter? I'm looking for a simple way to capitalize the character at position N of an ascii string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
$str[$n] = strtoupper($str[$n]);
```

Note that the position is zero-based, so for the second character in a string `$n = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

With an ascii string you can do that:

```
$str[$n] = strtoupper($str[$n]);
```

But this doesn't work with an unicode string, it works only if characters are encoded with one byte.

For a multibyte string *(utf8 for example)* :

```
mb_internal_encoding ('UTF-8');

$str = mb_substr($str, 0, $n) . mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, $n, 1)) . mb_substr($str, ++$n);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for names like McDonald, McKinney, McCall, etc.
Also, assumes there is only one instance of Mc in the string.

```
$newname = "Joe and Mary Mcdonald";
$position = stripos($newname, "Mc");  // case insensitive
$newname[$position + 2] = strtoupper($newname[$position + 2]);
echo $newname;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "teststring";
$pos = 5;
function toUpper($str, $pos) {
    return substr_replace($str, strtoupper(substr($str, ($pos-1), 1)), ($pos-1), 1) ;
}
echo toUpper($str, $pos);
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.